# .net Regex Performance consideration: Use (partial or global) case-insensitive matching or explicit character groups?

Tags: .net, regex, case-sensitive

In .net Regex's, there's the possibility to match case-insensitively by doing one of several possible things:

1. use explicit character groups, for example

   ```
   [Ff][Oo][Oo][Bb][Aa][Rr]
   ```
2. use case-insensitivity modifier on partial pattern or the full pattern, e.g.

   ```
   (?i)foobar
   foo(?i)bar(?-i)
   ```
3. turn on case-insensitivity for the Regex via `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

My question is now NOT about functionality or readability (this has been discussed in other questions), but about performance.

Does this make a difference? Is using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` faster than using character groups, and/or is using the inline options faster/slower than the groups or the `RegexOptions`?

Thx,
Tim

Comment: Have you tested anything yet?

Comment: you can use regexhero.net for performance comparison

Comment: I didn't know about regexhero, great stuff, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex Hero, I've tested three different expressions described in your question and it brought some insights on each performance test:

1. `[Ff][Oo][Oo][Bb][Aa][Rr]`
2. `(?i)foobar`
3. `foobar`  (using RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

Below you can find the performance for each case:

[image]

The test cases returned:

1. `[Ff][Oo][Oo][Bb][Aa][Rr]` performed **392,487** iterations per second
2. `(?i)foobar` performed **1,174,035** iterations per second (**199.1%** faster than 1)
3. `foobar` (using RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) performed **1,191,317** iterations per second (**1.5%** faster than 2)